# BCP Utility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bcp

I need to have ability in my application to be able to export some data using the SQL Server BCP utitility. The machines where this utility would run would not have SQL Native Client installed on it, so BCP.exe won't be present by default.

Can I put a version of BCP in the installation package. What are licensing implications?

I have tried using the version, which was shipped with SQL Server 2000 (2000.80.2039.0) and it works fine by just copying the BCP.exe and BCP.rll file over.

However, when I try to use the version, shipped with SQL Server 2005 (2005.90.3042.0), the file just doesn't do anything (no message or error is reported). Can anybody please tell me what other dependendies the BCP.exe is dependant upon. I tried using DependencyWalker and have copied sqlncli.dll and devmgr.dll but still no use.

Any help, pointers, etc. would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kragen2uk.
I had already used dependecy walker. In the end, I had to install SQL Server Native Client (Client Components) on the target machine. It's a free redistributable anyway.

Comment: since this is what you had to do and it solved your problem you should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try dependency walker for finding dependencies - freely available just google it.